# Issue installing Scikit learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, scikit-learn

I know this question has been up many times before and I've tried to follow the steps as outlined, but my scikit still won't work.

I have Python 3.11, on Windows 11, using Spyder. When trying to run the following code I get this error.

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

> File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line
> 356, in compat_exec
> exec(code, globals, locals)
> File "c:\users\XXX\documents\capex\python\untitled0.py", line 8, in 
> import sklearn
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

These are the things I've done/tried but still getting the issue.

- Run pip3.11 install scikit-learn in the terminal (resulting in Requirement already satisfied)
- Run python -m pip install -U pip (resulting in Requirement already satisfied)
- Adding the Python and Python/Script paths to Path in advanced settings, under both user and system sections.
- Removed Python from the settings with Microsoft store default (it wasn't there to start with)
- python -m pip show scikit-learn results in that it is installed, version 1.1.3
- When running `python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"` in the terminal it seems to work, but not when running import sklearn in Spyder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It may be that you installed spyder incorrectly. If you're launching spyder from the desktop, it would have been best to install it with anaconda. Try uninstalling your current spyder installation and using Anaconda to install spyder as well as your other scientific computing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current spyder installation and reinstall it with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/). Your terminal environment is fundamentally different from your overall environment. As such installing sci-kit learn on your Linux distro on terminal still doesn't give you access to the library elsewhere. Anaconda is the easiest way to install all the scientific computing packages you need.